# How to change the background of the tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have a tabhost with ~ 5 tabs,and I would like to change the background of it . There is a background image of the tabs , one rectangle image of all tabs. When I add to tabhost . It does not work. How to fix it? Thanks

```
   <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/tabBg"
   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this...

```
tabhost
 .getTabWidget()
 .getChildAt(/*Index of the tab of which you want to change the background*/)
 .setBackground(/*the background res you want to set */)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("orders")
       .setIndicator("Orders",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.flash_36))
       .setContent(R.id.ordersLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution

```
public void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
        for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
             tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.share_tab_bg)); // selected
        }
    }
```